# How to use layouts in .xml files : Android application

Tags: android

How can I use any layout in .xml files. Let I want to use Tablelayout, so I dragged it on Graphical Layout of an xml file, and then I want that layout should be in two columns ( if I want add "Name : " in first column and "EditText" in another column.) but I am anable to do it.I am using Graphical layout. I want do like

```
Name : EditText (A textbox for Name entry)
Age  : EditText (A textbox for Age entry)

              Button (to save user entry)
```

How to design it.

Comment: I always find its easier to go to the xml view and enter what I want by hand.  Drag and drop designing of layouts rarely works the way I want it to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:isScrollContainer="true"
>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_name"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"

        android:visibility="visible"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:nextFocusDown="@+id/mark"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_age"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"

        android:visibility="visible"
        android:maxLength="3"
        android:maxLines="1"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_save"
        android:text="@string/save"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:onClick="onButtonClick"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:enabled="false" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Put this into your XML
There you go ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would consider the same as ehudokai. If you are roughly familiar with XML, then try to use the graphical layout just to control if everything is working es expected.
In case you don't know how to create what you need in XML drag it to somewhere and cut & paste the code to the correct possition.
I think the graphical layout is quite good for editing the properties, so you see directly what you are changing.

Answer (score 0):

try out droiddraw...here is d link..
http://www.droiddraw.org/